# Using Microsoft filters in IE9 platform preview

Tags: css, filter, internet-explorer-9

I would like to use the [Matrix filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533014%28VS.85%29.aspx), however it does not work at all in IE9, unlike in IE8. Was the filter idea deprecated with the new version? Is here any way to get it working? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, they have removed filters in IE9 standard mode in favor of CSS3 styles. Try forcing IE8 mode with the following meta-tag or an equivalent HTTP header:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the new `-ms-filter` syntax?

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=50)";
```

And could you provide your current code?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it with/without vendor prefix, without quotes and all other combination.

Comment: I don't have any. I tried many variations but nothing worked. My question is whether __any__ ms filter works in the 3rd IE9 preview.

Comment: Can you at least post your variations?